# Onepage Checkout, unable to place the order getting Prototype.js error

Tags: magento-1.9

When i click on  Checkout as Guest or Register, I'm getting this error,Unable to proceed on any steps.

```
TypeError: e is not a function


...complete:!1,initialize:function(e,t,n){e(n),this.transport=Ajax.getTransport(),t...
```

How can i fix this..?
Thanks

Comment: Have you added any jquery code ? if any code post in question.

Comment: I have added jquery min file,but i think maybe my prototype.js file is corrupted

Comment: add jQuery.noConflict(); before jQuery code.

Comment: I have updated the prototype.js , Now its working

thanks :)